# Attach Sharepoint 2010 List attachment to gridview

Tags: sharepoint, gridview

I have a SharePoint list, which has attachments!!

I am using a custom grid-view to display some selected List fields from the list.

I would like to include the attachment as an embedded document in the Grid-view, Is that possible?

Comment: Its a custom gridview so everything is possible. What do you mean you want to show the documents as "embedded"? When an image is attached you want to display the image or are you talking about Word files?

Comment: why not have a hyper link(s) to your attachment(s)?

Comment: It is a word document, I thought it would be nice if I could show the file in the cell, on double click of the file, would like to open it in word file !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it worked, Created an anchor type item template in grid view.

And the `Href` property of the anchor tab is binded with the attachment retrieved pro grammatically. Working great!!